# setDate with getDate + n returns today's date + n

Tags: javascript

I want d2 to be d1 + 14 days, instead it's todays' date + 14 days.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var d1 = new Date(2014, 7, 1);
  var d2 = new Date();
  d2.setDate(d1.getDate() + 14);

  // d1 = Fri Aug 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
  document.write("d1 = " + d1);
  document.write("<br></br>")

  // today's date is 16-04-2014
  // d2 = Tue Apr 15 2014 17:36:03 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
  document.write("d2 = " + d2);
</script>
```

How can I make d2 = d1 + 14 days?

Comment: Maybe d2.setDay(d1.getDay() + 14); ?

Comment: @user3417400 getDay return `d2 = Tue Aug 19 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setDate`, somewhat surprisingly, sets the day-of-the-month of the existing instance. Since you've initialized `d2` with today, you're just changing the day-of-month for that date, not taking on any other aspect of `d1`.

You probably want:

```
var d1 = new Date(2014, 7, 1);  // A specific date
var d2 = new Date(d1);          // Clone that date
d2.setDate(d1.getDate() + 14);  // Move forward 14 days
```

That gives us August 1st for `d1`, and August 15th for `d2`.

Another option is:

```
var d1 = new Date(2014, 7, 1);
var d2 = new Date(d1.getFullYear(), d1.getMonth(), d1.getDate() + 14);
```

Both of those work even when you're going past the end of the month, btw.

Complete example of the second option: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/zahaxera/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Date plus 14 days</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var d1, d2;

      display("Starting with August 1st:")
      d1 = new Date(2014, 7, 1);
      d2 = new Date(d1.getFullYear(), d1.getMonth(), d1.getDate() + 14);
      display("d1 = " + d1);
      display("d1 = " + d2);
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));

      display("Starting with August 20th:")
      d1 = new Date(2014, 7, 20);
      d2 = new Date(d1.getFullYear(), d1.getMonth(), d1.getDate() + 14);
      display("d1 = " + d1);
      display("d1 = " + d2);

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: You know, it just might. Let me check the spec. *Edit*: Yup, the first thing the one-argument version of the `Date` constructor does is call `ToPrimitive` on what's passed in. `ToPrimitive` on `Date` instances gives us the numeric value. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

You're making a new Date (today) for d2 but only changing the day, this should work:

```
var d1 = new Date(2014, 7, 1);
var d2 = new Date(2014, 7, d1.getDate()+14);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only put **getTime()** function inside d2 **Date()** function,

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3X2f/)**</kbd>

#### JavaScript

```
  var d1 = new Date(2014, 7, 1);
  var d2 = new Date(d1.getTime());
  d2.setDate(d1.getDate() + 14);

  // d1 = Fri Aug 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
  document.write("d1 = " + d1);
  document.write("<br></br>")

  // today's date is 16-04-2014
  // d2 = Tue Apr 15 2014 17:36:03 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
  document.write("d2 = " + d2);
```

#### Result

```
d1 = Fri Aug 1 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014

d2 = Fri Aug 15 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

d1 is a date in August, d2 is today.  You are setting d2 to today + 14 days.  The proper result is below:

```
var d1 = new Date(2014, 7, 1);
var d2 = new Date(d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 12));
```